# How to unlock a row if i use FOR UPDATE clause

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

In procedure if we use `FOR UPDATE` clause, it will lock particular row and allow only one client to update whereas other client can only fetch data in the same row at that time.

My question is when will it unlock the row, what should we do to unlock the row while writing procedure?
Take this example here I'm using `FOR UPDATE` clause for client_count, when ll it unlock that particular row in this procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE newprocedur(inMerid IN VARCHAR2,outCount OUT NUMBER) AS 
CURSOR c1 IS 
  select CLIENT_COUNT 
    from OP_TMER_CONF_PARENT 
   where MER_ID = inMerid 
   FOR UPDATE OF CLIENT_COUNT;
BEGIN
  Open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into outCount;
    exit when c1%NOTFOUND;
    outCount:=outCount+1;
    update OP_TMER_CONF_PARENT 
       set CLIENT_COUNT = outCount 
     where current of c1;
  end loop;
  close c1;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The updated rows will be unlocked after a commit.

Comment: ... or a rollback. In short: when the transaction ends.

Comment: Or `roolback` statement. And be aware that if you issue `commit` or `rollback` statement after `update` statement you will not be able to execute another `fetch` against that `for update` cursor. It will result in `ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence`

Comment: Here, Multiple clients will call the above procedure at same time having same MER_ID, in that case i have to lock the row only one client should update the count at tat time and others should have the right only to fetch not update, so i am using FOR UPDATE clause.Am i doing it in right way??? or how should i modify the above code?