# How does SELECT FOR UPDATE works in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, select, transactions, synchronization

I am trying to do synchronization of transactions via DataBase. It's required, because i wand to synchronize transactions from two different systems (JVM's).
I try to do it with SELECT FOR UPDATE statement. But i don't sure in which moment rows would be unlocked. There are two suggestions:

- Rows would be unlocked on transaction completed
- Rows would be unlocked on closing ResultSet

Which of this two is right?

Comment: The lock will be removed upon `commit` or `rollback`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i will have doubts until i see it in official documentation. Can you provide links?

Comment: If you don't believe the people answering here, then why do you ask the question?

Comment: Btw: the "official documentation" is called the manual. And what you are asking for is the chapter about transactions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/transact.htm#CNCPT1119

Comment: Or [the chapter about PL/SQL static SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#CIHHIIID): "The rows of the result set are locked when you open a FOR UPDATE cursor, not as they are fetched. The rows are unlocked when you commit or roll back the transaction."

Comment: If I understand your needs (not sure at all), your problem is not you need to build a distributed transactions manager. See the Oracle documentation [link] https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/xadistra.htm

Comment: same question, same answer: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151701/how-to-unlock-a-row-if-i-use-for-update-clause